# Can not install brew on mac

Tags: terminal, mac, command-line, bash, homebrew

when i am using

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

or

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

i receive the following situation

```
USER@MacBook-Air ~ % /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
==> Checking for `sudo` access (which may request your password).
Password:
==> This script will install:
/usr/local/bin/brew
/usr/local/share/doc/homebrew
/usr/local/share/man/man1/brew.1
/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_brew
/usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d/brew
/usr/local/Homebrew

Press RETURN to continue or any other key to abort
==> /usr/bin/sudo /usr/sbin/chown -R USER:admin /usr/local/Homebrew
==> Downloading and installing Homebrew...
HEAD is now at 163cee5ce small correcting in README.md
/bin/bash: line 160: /usr/local/bin/brew: No such file or directory
Failed during: /usr/local/bin/brew update --force --quiet
USER@MacBook-Air ~ %
```

i don't know what to do in this situation. My operation system is MacOS Big Sur 11.5.2.

Comment: Did you have homebrew installed before?

Answer (score 2):

I'd try running the uninstaller and then try installing it again.

To uninstall use:

```
/bin/bash -c "$[github.com/homebrew/install#uninstall-homebrew](curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/uninstall.sh)"
```

Or download the uninstall script and run:

```
/bin/bash uninstall.sh --help
```

... to view more uninstall options.

The uninstall *command* is from: (https://github.com/homebrew/install#uninstall-homebrew)

Answer (score 0):

Run

```
sudo find / -iname '*brew*' 2>/dev/null
```

To find files on your system that are already related to homebrew.

The output might be

```
/usr/local/bin/brew
/usr/local/share/doc/homebrew
/usr/local/share/man/man1/brew.1
/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_brew
/usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d/brew
/usr/local/Homebrew
```

for example.

Curate the list, remove anything that's not actually homebrew so that you don't wreck your system or lose data, e.g. don't let yourself delete `/Users/Ерванд/Movies/SabreWorld.mkv`.

Then you should delete everything that's left:

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/brew
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/share/doc/homebrew
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/share/man/man1/brew.1
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_brew
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d/brew
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/Homebrew
```

As mentioned, be careful of course: this is a permanent and irreversible deletion. Don't delete anything that wasn't installed by homebrew.

After cleaning your system of anything left over from previous brew installations, install it again:

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

Comment: @user3439894 that's a really good idea. I didn't even think that there may have been such a script available to use with some weird partial installation. You could post an answer suggesting to use it? It's definitely a better first try than the riskier/more time-consuming manual deletion I suggested